# $2 \sin 3θ + 1 = 0$ Find solutions and solutions in the given interval

Tags: trigonometry

An equation is give (express your answer in terms of k, where k is any integer)

$$2 sin 3θ + 1 = 0$$

(a) Find all solutions of the equation.

(b) Find the solutions in the interval $[$$0$, $2π$$)$.

Part A (answer on bottom right of picture):

[image]
Need help with part b. How do I find all the solutions in the given interval?

Comment: plug values for $k$ and see which fall in the interval given.

Comment: Which values do I plug in?

Comment: $0,\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, ...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that equivalently $\sin 3\theta = -\frac{1}{2}$ is also satisfied for $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{11\pi}{6}$, and full revolutions from these points.  We can therefore have that

$$
3\theta \;\; =\;\; \frac{7\pi}{6} + 2\pi k \hspace{2pc} \text{or} \hspace{2pc} 3\theta \;\; =\;\; \frac{11\pi}{6} + 2\pi k
$$

where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  These equations can be rewritten as

$$
\theta \;\; =\;\; \frac{(7 + 12k)\pi}{18} \hspace{2pc} \text{or} \hspace{2pc} \theta \;\; =\;\;  \frac{(11+12k)\pi}{18}.
$$

To find which values are contained in $[0,2\pi)$, we see which values of $k$ allow the above quantities to be $\geq 0$ but $<2\pi$.  The solution set is found to be

$$
\left \{\frac{7\pi}{18}, \frac{11\pi}{18}, \frac{19\pi}{18}, \frac{23\pi}{18}, \frac{31\pi}{18}, \frac{35\pi}{18} \right \}.
$$

These values are obtained by plugging in $k=0,1,2$ into the above equations.  You can verify that these are all less than $2\pi$ and the only solutions which are nonnegative.

Comment: Do you always plug in $k=0,1,2$ as long as the domain is 0 to 2π (not including 2π)?

Comment: @TheNewGuy With these types of equations you need to look at your complete solution set, in this case given by the two equations for $\theta$, and then see which values from the $\theta$-equations lie in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.  It turns out in this case that when you plug in $0,1,2$ into the $\theta$-equations, these are the only values that lie in the set.  I would be wary of trying to find some algorithmic way of plugging in numbers for problems like these.

Comment: Thank you! One more thing: I'm doing a similar problem and this time there are four solutions and I need to find the solutions which lie in the interval $[0,2π)$. So for each solution I need to substitute $k=1,2,$ and $3$? So therefore I will have 12 solutions total in the given interval?

Comment: @TheNewGuy Without seeing the actual problem, I can't really say.  Plug in an integer into your full solution and see if that particular value lies in the interval $[0,2\pi)$.  If the value lies in there, then it's part of your solution, if the value is not in there then your value of $k$ is either too high or too low and you should try plugging numbers in the opposite direction.  Keep doing this until you exhaust all of your options.

Comment: when I set $k=1$ it yields a result of over 7, and the higher $k$ is the higher it goes. Is there another way to find out what k is? Should I make another post?

Comment: The question is on the top $3csc^2 θ = 4$

Here is the work. Same instructions as the previous question. I boxed the four solutions, how do I find $k$?

http://i.imgur.com/HXsreUs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> $$2 \sin 3θ + 1 = 0$$

$$ \sin 3θ  = -1/2$$

$\theta=\frac{7 \pi}{18}+\frac{2 \pi n}{3},\;3\theta=\frac{11 \pi}{6}+2\pi n$

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{\frac{1}{18}(12\pi n-\pi)}}$$

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{\frac{1}{18}(12\pi n+7\pi)}}$$

$$n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2\sin(3\theta)+1 = 0 \implies \sin(3\theta) = -1/2 $

But $-1/2 = \cos(\pi/6)$ which corresponds to $\sin(\pi+\pi/6)$

So we have $\sin(7\pi/6) = \sin(3\theta)$

But $\sin(x) = \sin(y)  \iff y = \cdots$